Kproto, Kmeans and Gower with PAM (General Clustering Analysis)
Hi I have around 654 rows of data with mixed variables (both numeric and categorical). I have done all the scaling, transformation for numerical variables and replaced missing in both numerical and categorical variables with means and modes respectively. I have done k-proto with my mixed variables and Gower with PAM. I also did One-hot Encoding and ran kmeans on the data. My question is that every time I run K-proto it gives me different types of clusters. I have set the seed and kept maximum iteration to 500 and nstart to 1. My question probably is more theoretical: If I am not setting the seed and keeping all the iterations to 500 and nstart to 1 and the result changes every time, what is the purpose then of doing clustering?
